# Insert link to email in outlook with yasoon (or native plugin)

Tags: email, plugins, outlook

Is it possible to modify email contents in outlook with yasoon?
I need to develop a plugin that opens html+js popup and inserts a link to email that user composes currently. Also I have to get list of recipients.
More details on what I want to archive is in this video(1.5 minutes) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JDh1NdIeUM

if its not possible with yasoon - how can I develop such functionality in outlook 2010/2013?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is fully supported by yasoon. We do something similar for [Dropbox](https://github.com/yasoonOfficial/com.yasoon.dropbox). However a heads up, there is also a way using the new Microsoft "Outlook Apps" to support [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/dn574748.aspx) functionality. See the "Compose scenario" section. This would also allow you to run your app on Outlook.com website as well. yasoon only supports the standalone Outlook desktop client.

In case you need something more than just a simple html+js view and adding a link, like accessing the calendar (read, write), creating a ribbon button or new popup dialogs, feel free to check out our GitHub repo for code samples any time!

Answer (score 0):

I bielive you can develop an Outlook add-in with a form region where you can choose and enter all the custom information. And then create a hyperlink and insert it in the body. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started.

Also you may find the [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) section in MSDN helpful.